# Amazon saying S3 bucket doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-s3

I created a bucket on Amazon S3 and went to the url (which is a url I need to put in an initializer in my rails app)

```
https://mtest73.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

and got this message

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>mtest73</BucketName>
<RequestId>9FBDCC50303F4306</RequestId>
<HostId>
owG6PSSjvcS7QZwEMKzTjMnYiwclXkRG7QGIF/Ly+jc8mHnmbvWHXqitDzfjnzgM
</HostId>
</Error>
```

However, in the Amazon console i've even uploaded a small file to this bucket. [image]

Is there a reason for this? I thought it might be saying the bucket doesn't exist due to security reasons, but if there's something I've done wrong it might be why I can't get my Rails application to work...

Comment: The S3 console says "m73test" and your URL said "mtest73."

Comment: mtest73 or m73test? Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

@JohnFlatness and @pjotr pointed out, I wrote the wrong url

```
https://mtest73.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

It should have been

https://73mtest.s3.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Good. The title scared the hell out of me.